# Получаем название файла и записываем его

Tags: php, javascript, html

Здравствуйте, проблема такая: есть форма загрузки файла

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Загрузка файлов на сервер</title>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>

  <body>
  <h2><p><b> Форма для загрузки файлов </b></p></h2>
  <form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="file" name="filename"><br> 
  <input type="submit" value="Загрузить"><br>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

И обработчик :

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Результат загрузки файла</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
<?php

if($_FILES["filename"]["size"] > 1024*8*1024)
{
 echo ("Размер файла превышает три мегабайта");
 exit;
 }
// Проверяем загружен ли файл
if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES["filename"]["tmp_name"]))
{
 // Если файл загружен успешно, перемещаем его
 // из временной директории в конечную
  move_uploaded_file($_FILES["filename"]["tmp_name"], "".$_FILES["filename"]      ["name"]);
    echo("Загружен");
 } else {
   echo("Ошибка загрузки файла");
 }

 ?>
```

Как сделать так, чтобы можно было записать название файла в текстовый документ?

Comment: не совсем понятно, в какой текстовый документ Вы хотите записать название файла? В какой-то отдельный документ? Все загруженные файлы в один документ или каждый раз разные? под "названием" Вы имеет ввиду имя файла? Вобщем, по-понятней задачу разъясните, пожалуйста.

Comment: Названия файлов (имя файла), каждое с новой строки в один файл с разрешением тхт

Answer (score 1):

Если дописываешь в файл например files.txt, то используй :

`fopen('files.txt','a');fwrite и fclose;`

Пример :

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Результат загрузки файла</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
<?php

if($_FILES["filename"]["size"] > 1024*8*1024)
{
 echo ("Размер файла превышает три мегабайта");
 exit;
 }
// Проверяем загружен ли файл
if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES["filename"]["tmp_name"]))
{
 // Если файл загружен успешно, перемещаем его
 // из временной директории в конечную
  move_uploaded_file($_FILES["filename"]["tmp_name"], "".$_FILES["filename"]      ["name"]);
    echo("Загружен");
    if($f=fopen('files.txt','a')){
         fwrite($f,$_FILES["filename"]["name"]."\n");
         fclose($f);
    }
 } else {
   echo("Ошибка загрузки файла");
 }

 ?>
```